# Click-event is lost after a while

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, xpages

I have built an XPage with a click event for a button, that writes data in the session scope.

```
<xp:button value="all" id="button4">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="norefresh">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.selectedView = "view1";print("view1!");}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

After some clicks the print output "view1" is not displayed anymore. So the event somewhere has gone lost and I have no idea why this has happened.

Answer (score 0):

It should not happen if you click continuously every e.g. 5 seconds, no matter how many clicks you made. Does it really happens that way?

If it stops working after some period of inactivity, check `Application Timeout` and `Session Timeout` properties of your application. When the session gets destroyed on time-out, all the views are also purged, so the engine does not have any target for your POST request anymore.

Increase the session and application timeouts, or much better use `keepSessionAlive` component that is the part of Extension Library